# Remote Desktop or locally installed app

Tags: remote-desktop, network-share

I have two working points at 5 km distances. All the servers are in point A. The connection between this point is made via radio link ( 20 -30 Mbps ).

In such cases from network bandwith, can you please tell me, which option is more friendly:

1. users form working point B would conect via thin client by remote desktop to servers from point A. All aplication would be installed on those servers.
2. users form working point B would have PC whith software installed locally and will acces the databases and file servers via radio link.

Thank you

Comment: What sort of latency do you typically see on this link?

Comment: How many users?

Comment: What's the app's bandwidth usage?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing relevant to you application I suggest you simply test both options and see which works best for your particular situation. There are far too many variables with this kind of thing for us to give you any more than an educated guess but even for that we would need to know a lot more than you have told us. Even if you were to give us more information we still couldn't do any better recommendation that what you can get from an actual test.